# Generate executable larger than 4GB with TurboStudio

Tags: virtualization

Thinapp has no problem generating virtual applications above 4GB.
Whenever I try something similar with TurboStudio it fails. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after several experiments I think I found an answer.
Spoon Studio (or Turbo Studio as it is now called) cannot create executables larger than 4GB. Checking the "Compress Payload" option reduces output size, but these captures perform usually a bit slower (due to the decompression required at runtime) and of course, there are always apps that will exceed the 4GB limit even with this option checked.

A workaround, however, is to divide the installation process in multiple captures (when possible) and use svm files.

For example, assume you are capturing a large application (Myapp) and some addons or plugins to it which together generate a capture larger than 4GB in size.

The solution would then be to first capture the application without any addons. Then install the plugins/addons and capture them separately. When you capture the plugins choose as Project Type "Component". At the end of this process you will have a captured application in executable "myapp.exe" and the plugins captured separately in "plugins.svm". It is possible to repeat this process several times, thus ending with "myapp.exe" and multiple SVMs, such as "plugins.svm", "plugins02.svm" etc.

In order to load the "plugins.svm" in "myapp.exe" without importing it as a component (which would defeat the purpose as it would still blow up the size beyond 4GB), go to Settings-->Process Configuration-->SVMs.
In the SVM search pattern you enter a text string to specify the SVMs to be loaded during startup of the application.

You can specify a single SVM by entering something like
`@APPDIR@\plugins.svm`
or multiple SMVs by entering something like
`@APPDIR@\plugins.svm;@APPDIR@\plugins02.svm`
or even use a wildcard by entering something like
`@APPDIR@\*.svm`

All of the above examples imply that the desired SVMs exist in the application's folder. Else, use a different path.

If multiple SVMs are specified in one search pattern through the use of the '*' wildcard, the SVMs are applied in reverse-alphabetical priority.

If SVMs are specified by name (not with a wildcard), then the SVMs specified first in the list will take precedence over SVMs specified later in the list.

You can also make specific svm files Required, by adding them to the "Required SVM name" list. In this case, the application won't start if it doesn't find the SVM file in the specified location and will instead give an error message that a required SVM was not located.

I hope this will be of help to people trying to capture large applications and hitting the 4GB limit with Turbo (Spoon) Studio.